# npm dependencies (serverless framework) isn't installed in the latest version on Jenkins (CJE)

Tags: jenkins, npm, serverless, cloudbees

I am trying to deploy a node.js project (serverless framework application to be specified). Although it is not error related, but I found the console of Jenkins output look like this 
[image]

But in the package.json files, I actually specify the version of serverless to be at least 1.38.0

```
"serverless": "^1.38.0",
```

Hard to know the reason for this,  appreciate to the help of any kinds

Comment: are you able to change the node version and/or other npm dependencies through package.json?

Comment: @N8888 Thanks, I will try that later, but i am sure it is okay to npm install new dependencies,